# Override keys in the Cargo.toml manifest using the cargo command

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a very simple Cargo.toml file

```
[package]
name = "example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [Test Author]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "example_lib"
path = "lib.rs"
```

and I would like to override the keys `path` and `name` in the [lib] section dynamically, without modifying the toml file directly. For example, I imagine using the command `cargo build --override_keys ="lib.name=\"new_lib\""` to build my library while also overriding the output name of the generated library file.

Is something like this possible? I have not found a good answer. The only thing I stumbled upon was [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6699) proposal, but it seems to be made for a different purpose.

Comment: It might help to know more about your use case. What's the end goal?

Comment: I have a folder with Rust files that have identical dependencies but different behaviour. These files are generated by a tool. I need to produce differently named library files (WASM binaries) that are loaded into an application. I would like to quickly switch between the files when producing a binary. So for n Rust files I would like to produce n WASM binaries, all differently named. In Make this is possible using different environment variables and targets but I do not know the equivalent in Cargo.